# How to use all project contents in a newly created project?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I have an existing .net wpf project developped using Visual Studio and I just created a new project and I want this project to use all contents of my existing project and able to run the new one just like the existing one. I know I can copy and paste all contents but it is not the way I want to do it. As I want to use conditional symbols so that two projects will behave different despite having the same content.

I made some research about this. There are some suggestions to add other project files as "link" to the new one. But, I am not sure if this would be an appropriate solution as when I make changes in my existing project, new one may not have those changes? Any idea that could be the best and most efficient way to handle this?

Comment: Give us more information. Why do you want to create a "new" project with exactly the same files/content?

Comment: Because I want to use conditional symbols so that two projects will behave different despite having the same content.

Comment: "I want to use conditional symbols" - typically you'd do that in different configurations of the *same* project, just like how Debug and Release builds work. Is there a reason you don't want to do that?

Comment: Yes, there is a reason. It is something about that I want my project to run on windows startup but as my existing project have "UAC" in manifest file, it is impossible to do that. I created a new project without manifest file. Thats why I need something weird like this.